# How to add a property to one element of an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to add a property to a singular element of an array.

Basically, I want to choose a singular element at random, make it appear on screen, then after it disappears add a "already chosen" property to that element so that it can't be randomly picked again.

Alternatively, if anyone knows how to temporarily exclude a single element from an array, that would be extremely helpful too.

```
const numbers =["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? `element.chosen = true` would probably work just fine

Comment: If you want to make sure no element is picked twice you might as well just [*shuffle*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954) the array once beforehand and iterate.

Comment: Please be more specific on what you have tried so others can understand better

Answer (score 0):

you can use array of object this way

```
let values = [
  {
    "value": "1",
    "picked": "false",
  },
  {
    "value": "2",
    "picked": "false",
  }
  ,
  {
    "value": "3",
    "picked": "false",
  }
  ,
  {
    "value": "4",
    "picked": "false",
  }
  ,
  {
    "value": "5",
    "picked": "false",
  }
]
```

and every time that you pick a number give the true value to picked property